# DB reverse engineering with symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

According to http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html the author generates `.xml` database description.

But there is no explanation what that descriptions can be used for: we generate php classes with annotations anyway, and they work regardless `.xml` metadata.

So, what are they for?

And is there any "best practices" article about common using migrations workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML mapping descriptions comes in place of Annotations-based mapping. You have to choose between YAML, XML, Annotations and PHP for mapping descriptions...

In the process on the official documentation, the first set of generated .xml files is the same as the second one, but without namespaces resolution. This can't be done at the first step (i guess for relations between entites..), so you need 2 steps. After Entities generation, you can delete the first set of .xml files.

Comment: hm, I can create `.php` models without `.xml` descriptions

Comment: @zerkms yes, because you're using annotation instead of xml.. Entities can be configured in different ways

Comment: @Inori: yep, and my question is "why the author generates both"? They even say "Once the metadata files are generated, you can ask Doctrine to import the schema and build related entity classes by executing the following two commands." which confuses me a lot.

Comment: When you use `.xml` you don't need to create a separate `.php` entity class, it is generated automatically via `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities`. The process is generate xml metada > generate entities that represent metadata. Whereas if you use `annotation` you basically skip the metadata part and configure representation directly. Which one is better is debatable and mostly preference question, much like `.xml` vs `.yml` for app config.

Comment: @Inori: so in the article they just made unneeded step?

Comment: it's not unneeded, it's another way of configuring entities.. They also mention that you can use .yml instead of .xml, so probably direct reverse engineering to annotation format is not possible.

Comment: @Inori: Ok, it is unneeded if we use models with annotations. Right? If yes - if we use models with annotations - may `xml/yml` descriptions be used for something?